# can we evaluate this closed contour integration of involving coth and cos?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I would like to evaluate the integral,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{x} (\cos[2 \pi s x])^2\coth[2 \pi x b]$$,

where s and b are some real parameters.

I tried to close the contour in the upper or lower half plane but it doesn't seem to converge to me, because of the squared cosine term (which leads to a constant term which therefore is not exponentially supressed), so my next attempt was a rectangular contour- but no luck so far.

Comment: Your integral doesn’t converge? The singularity at $x=0$ is not removable. If you wanted to evaluate this, use the fact the integral is even and make it go from $0$ to $\infty$ and then you could use the Mittag-Leffler pole expansion for $\cot (z)$ and manipulate it for a series for $\operatorname{coth} (2\pi x b)$ then the rest is trivial to evaluate with something like a Laplace transform method for example. But anyway, you get a diverging integral. (If it were $\sin$ instead of $\cos$ or $\operatorname{coth} -\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $\operatorname{coth}$, it would converge).

Comment: thanks! could you be a little more explicit about the method you suggested? i dont mind the divergence at the origin because i can apply some regularisation scheme and ignore that divergence

Comment: $$\operatorname{coth}(2\pi x b)=\frac{1}{2\pi x b}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4\pi x b}{(2\pi x b)^2+(k \pi)^2}$$ by [the Mittag-Leffler pole expansion of $\cot (z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem). Now $$I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\cos^2 (2\pi s x)\operatorname{coth}(2\pi b x)\, dx =2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\cos^2 (2\pi s x)\operatorname{coth}(2\pi b x)\, dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2\cos^2 (2\pi s x)}{x(2\pi x b)}\, dx+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{8\pi x b \cos^2 (2\pi s x)}{x((2\pi x b)^2+(k\pi)^2)}\, dx$$

Comment: Now you can use a method such as exploting this [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the Laplace transform to evaluate these two integrals. (Consider $\mathcal{L}_x (\cos^2 (2\pi s x))(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_x \left(\frac{1}{\pi bx^2}\right)(t)$ for the first integral and $\mathcal{L}_x (\cos^2 (2\pi s x))(t)$ with $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_x\left(\frac{8\pi b}{(2\pi xb)^2+(k\pi)^2}\right)(t)$ for the second).